# Which are the sets that are not in the Sigma algebra generated by the random experiment of infinite coin toss

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

While reading "Stochastic Calculus for finance,volume 2,Steven E Shreve" I came across the fact that there exists sets which are not in **F_inf** ,the Sigma algebra generated by the random experiment of infinite coin toss. What kind of sets are those?

Comment: You cannot explcitly write down such sets. In fact you require Axiom of Choice to prove the existence.

Comment: i think this is a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457569/question-about-the-sigma-algebra-for-infinite-coin-toss)