# Is the Axiom of Choice inconsistent with Countable Additivity?

Tags: probability-theory, axiom-of-choice, axioms

Consider a fair lottery among a countably infinite number of people. The Axiom of Countable Additivity says this is impossible to construct: If all people have a positive (and equal) probability of winning, the sum of their probabilities of winning would diverge, while if all people have a $0$ probability of winning, the sum of their probabilities would be $0 \neq 1$.

However, I feel like the Axiom of Choice can be used to construct such a lottery:

1. Have each person select an element from $[0, 1)$. This is possible even with the Axiom of Countable Additivity.

**Lemma:** With probability $1$ everyone will have different numbers.
**Proof:**
Let $X_i$ be the number selected by $i$. Let $Y_{ij} = X_i - X_j \mod 1$. In order for two numbers to be equal with nonzero probability, there must be a nonzero probability that at least one $Y_{ij}$ equals $0$. But for all $i$ and $j$, $Y_{ij}$ is distributed uniformly and at random on $[0, 1)$. This means that there is this same nonzero probability that at least one of the $Y_{ij}$ equals $x$ for *every* $x \in [0, 1)$. Countable additivity would then lead to a divergent sum when considering the probabilities at least one of $Y_{ij} = 1/2$, $Y_{ij} = 1/3$, $Y_{ij} = 1/4$, and so on.

3. Choose a well-order on $[0, 1)$ using the Axiom of Choice.
4. Declare the person with the least number according to this well-order the winner.

What goes wrong with this reasoning? Or is it actually the case that these two axioms are inconsistent with each other?

Comment: On a side note to the below, it doesn't really make sense to say the axioms of probability are inconsistent with the AC. The axioms of probability aren't axioms in the same sense that choice is, they're definitions of what a probability space is. This would be better summarized as an argument that some fragment of ZFC is inconsistent that uses ideas from probability theory.

Comment: Presumably you want to perform step 3 so each possible well-order on $[0,1)$ is equally likely.  How were you planning to do that?

Comment: See a related discussion [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430439/how-to-show-that-the-event-that-a-prisoner-does-not-go-free-is-not-measurable)

Comment: There is an error in step 2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Presumably your sample space is $[0,1]^\mathbb N$ with probability measure the product of Lebesgue measure on each coordinate.  Then "events" such as "person #1 wins the lottery" are not events, i.e. they are not measurable sets for this measure, and as such can not be assigned probabilities.

Comment: I'm arguing that the very axioms of probability are inconsistent. You seem to be saying "You're proof is wrong because it results in something contradictory to the axioms of probability." Is that right? If so, it doesn't really do anything to confront my seeming paradox.

Comment: @JosephCamacho -- how do you prove that "everyone has a positive (and equal) probability of winning"? What is the probability, say, that person $1$ wins? How would you calculate it?

Comment: @JosephCamacho Unless you show by some other means that the winning sets for the players *are* measurable, there's no inconsistency.

Comment: I see. So, there isn't a contradiction between the axioms, but probability spaces are nevertheless not as expressive as I would hope. If I understand right, I *did* just construct an infinite fair lottery, yet it can't be represented as a probability space.

Comment: @JosephCamacho Also, the winner is determined by which well-ordering you choose at step 3, and I can't see any way that choice can be made 'fair'.  If you choose a well-ordering that gives low ranks to the sort of numbers that player 1 tends to choose, you'll tend to make player 1 win.

Comment: @ThomasLumley Each player chooses their number from the same distribution, so it doesn't matter what ordering is chosen.

Answer (score 3):

*Edit: In this answer I'm assuming the well-order of the reals is fixed at the outset and not somehow "chosen randomly", though, as commenter on another answer has woken me up to, you phrased the question as if were part of a random process. This would be a whole other can of worms (What distribution does this come from?! Is it independent of the sequence drawn?) but it doesn't affect the upshot of this answer.*

*Edit 2: Decided I didn't quite agree with how I put my original answer so rewrote it a bit.*

---

Here's a simpler example, that misses some features of yours but is more direct.

Say we have two players, and a non-Lebesgue-measurable set $E\subseteq [0,1],$ and some measure-zero set $C\subseteq [0,1]\setminus E.$ Draw a value $x\in[0,1]$ uniformly at random (i.e. via the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$), and player 1 wins if $x\in E$, it is a draw if $x\in C,$ and otherwise player 2 wins.

Unlike in your case, there's no intuition telling us that player 1 and 2 have equal probability to win, but some other features are there. For instance, since the draw set is measure zero, you would expect the probabilities of player 1 winning and player 2 winning to add up to $1$, as you expect in your case since the event of a tie (subsumed by the event of not having all points of the sequence distinct) is measure zero.

But of course we said we'd pick $x$ according to the Lebesgue measure, then asked what the probability of an event outside the Lebesgue measure was. There is no answer to this question.

Your example is not different in any essential way. In order to say you have 'equal nonzero probabilities for all players' you'd need to show that the events that they win are 1) measurable according to the probability space your sequence is coming from 2) have equal measure and 3) partition almost all of the probability space. If you could do that, there'd be a problem, since as your initial argument (or just common sense) shows, there cannot be infinitely many disjoint measurable sets with the same probability... the probabilities would have to add to infinity. But you can't do that, or at least, per Robert Israel's answer, there's no obvious reason to believe you can pass step 1.

So what can we say about these scenarios? Do they meaningfuly constitute a "lottery"? While we certainly couldn't execute either of these plans in the real world, perhaps it's not too much strain on the mathematical imagination to imagine actually having in hand some 'randomly drawn' $x\in[0,1]$... and if we did, it would certainly either be in $E$, or in $C$, or in neither. We could further imagine doing this over and over, tabulating the results. What would happen?

I don't know of any way of making sense of this, though we seem to have left mathematics and entered philosophy. (But perhaps it's just my ignorance. [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/13840) seems to suggest that you can use outer measure to represent limiting frequencies, but I haven't looked into it, and it seems rather drastic to give up countable additivity.) The abstract probability space formalism is our typical way of making rigorous mathematical sense of the idea of probability, so it seems odd to try to operate outside its jurisdiction on a question like this. Perhaps we've just hit a limit of how much we can extrapolate our intuition into math.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers give the theoretical reasons why this doesn't contradict the axioms of probability. In practice, what goes wrong is as follows. Let's assume you have assigned random reals to each player, that is, each player has an infinite string of digits, and they're all different. You also have chosen a well-ordering on the reals.

Now you want to decide who has won. How do you do that? There is no obvious algorithm, even one that uses infinitely many steps, because comparing approximations for these reals will never stabilise to the actual ordering.

So you haven't really constructed a lottery, fair or otherwise, since there's no way to carry out step 4.

Comment: If you're gonna make a computability-type argument, you first run into trouble at step 3 (building the well order in the first place), not step 4. If you accept that you can build the well order in the first place then it is reasonable to assume that you have some oracle for using it for comparison (even though this is not a computable function).